# Parse a page which populates content through javascript

Tags: php, javascript, xpath, xhtml

I am trying to parse a page which updates internal contents through javascript. When I look at the html through Firebug, it lookes like below:

```
<div id="productinfo">
<h2>
<span id="productname">Computer</span>
</h2>
<span id="servieidLabel" style=""> Service ID: </span>
<span id="snLabel" style="display: none"> Serial Number: </span>
<span id="servidno">12345ABCD</span>
```

However, when I right click the page and see the source, below is the structure of html:

```
<div id="productinfo">
<h2><span id="productname"></span></h2>
<span id="serviceidLabel" style="display: none"> 
Service ID:  
</span> 
<span id="snLabel" style="display: none">
Serial Number: 
</span> 
<span id="servidno"></span><br>

javascript:
warrantyPage.warrantycheck.displayProductInfo('Computer', true,'12345ABCD', false, '');
```

I am trying to parse and get the output like **Service ID: 12345ABCD**. Pls help me how to go about it. I have tried below code without any result because obviously service id number is not part of html but inserted by javascript

```
$servid = $xpath->query("//span[@id='servidno']");
foreach ($servid as $entry) {
echo "Service Id No:" ,$entry->nodeValue."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Since its unlikely you will be executing the javascript in the page, you will need to get the data from the same place the page gets it. This could be an ajax request or could be put in the page somewhere.

Comment: Although the span with `servidno` is not part of the **original** HTML, it **is** a part of the DOM. Since jQuery queries the DOM, it can find it. When do you run this code fragment? You must ensure to run it **after** the JavaScript fragment has generated the additional DOM elements.

Comment: You could use a regexp on the entire HTML to extract the information from the javascript part of the page. As you write the line `warrantyPage.warrantycheck.displayProductInfo('Computer', true,'12345ABCD', false, '');` is searchable with regexp.

Comment: If someone creates page like this (data populated by javascript without ajax call), it is most likely to prevent people/bots from scraping it like you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if javascript populating function always have the same parameters order, you can try to parse it:

```
$text = "warrantyPage.warrantycheck.displayProductInfo('Computer', true,'12345ABCD', false, '');";

preg_match_all('/\'[^\']+\'/', $text, $result);

print_r($result);
```

the result will be an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Computer'
            [1] => '12345ABCD'
        )
)
```

**The another method without regex:**

```
    $text = "warrantyPage.warrantycheck.displayProductInfo('Computer', true,'12345ABCD', false, '');";

    $tail = substr($text, strpos($text, "displayProductInfo(") + 19 , -1);

    $head = strstr($tail, ")", true);

    $args = explode(',', $head);
```

the $args will become an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'Computer'
    [1] =>  true
    [2] => '12345ABCD'
    [3] =>  false
    [4] =>  ''
)
```

Comment: Yes, regex is an alternative, but I am pathetic with it. Also, it'll be less stable as the whole page will have lot of other stuffs with chances of things being changed. I was wondering if there is any other method than regex

Comment: added another method, without regexp